# How to redirect to notification page when app is opened after clicking FCM notification?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-navigation

I have implemented firebase cloud messaging in my app successfully. But when a new notification appears, my app should open and then redirect to the notifications page from app.js.
The app is showing log info when the notification is clicked but when I try `this.props.navigator.push("Notification");` in that function, it shows an error `undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.push)`

I am guessing this is because I haven't yet initialised my stacknavigator but I don't know this for sure. I am using react-navigation in my app.

Here is the function in my app.js that gets called when the notification is clicked.

```
    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      console.log('getInitialNotification:');
      this.props.navigator.push("Notification");
    }
```

Also, the navigation code is not working even in my render function in app.js so I think props is not initialised in app.js.
Can anyone help me fix this and land me to the notification page?

Comment: Attach the code of your `app.js` too in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you have a route called `Notification` in your stack navigator and also your `app.js` has access to the navigator's `navigation` prop, then you might want to use **`this.props.navigation.navigate('Notification')`** in case you are using `react-navigation`.

**The problem with your code is this.props.navigation doesn't have any method called push so it will surely give an undefined error. To know more about navigation prop consider going through this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html).**

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('Notification')` also returns the same reult. How can I give my app.js access to the navigator's prop? I am using a stack navigator with drawer navigator which is initialised in another nacigation component.

Comment: For such a situation, I make my notification listeners go in a base component which is containing the navigator other than app.js  so that you can have the navigator's ref and then you can then use navigation dispatches to navigate to a specific route.